# How do I use JLabel in ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, jlabel

I am trying to show a text saying "The background is (color)" whenever I press a button that has the name of the color written on it but the text doesn't show up.

How it is supposed to be:
[image: example image my professor uploaded]

but mine is like this:
[image: my screenshot of this code]

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ThreeBtn extends JFrame {
    private JButton btnRed;
    private JButton btnGreen;
    private JButton btnBlue;
    
    
     public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
         
         public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
             if (e.getSource() == btnRed) {
                 (getContentPane()).setBackground(Color.red);
                 JLabel label = new JLabel("빨간색 배경입니다."); //it means "The background is red" in Korean               label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 25));
                 label.setForeground(Color.yellow);
                 (getContentPane()).add(label);
             }
             else if(e.getSource()==btnGreen) {
                 (getContentPane()).setBackground(Color.green);
                 JLabel label = new JLabel("초록색 배경입니다."); //it means "The background is green" in Korean
                 label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 25));
                 label.setForeground(Color.yellow);         
                 (getContentPane()).add(label);
             }
             else if(e.getSource()==btnBlue) {
                 (getContentPane()).setBackground(Color.blue);
                 JLabel label = new JLabel("파란색 배경입니다."); //it means "The background is blue" in Korean
                 label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 25));
                 label.setForeground(Color.yellow); 
                 (getContentPane()).add(label);
             }
         }
     }
     
     public ThreeBtn() {
         setSize(300, 200);
         setTitle("Three Button Example");
         setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         
         Container cPane = getContentPane();
         cPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
         btnRed = new JButton("RED");
         btnGreen = new JButton("GREEN");
         btnBlue = new JButton("Blue");
         
         ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
         btnRed.addActionListener(listener);
         btnGreen.addActionListener(listener);
         btnBlue.addActionListener(listener);
         
         cPane.add(btnRed);
         cPane.add(btnGreen);
         cPane.add(btnBlue);
         

     }
     
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         (new ThreeBtn()).setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

I am wondering if I used JLabel in a wrong way in the ActionListener but I can't figure it out.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you add new components to your GUI on runtime, you should use `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the parent container where the modification happened. This will tell swing, that there was new stuff added, which should be considered.

Comment: So if you add `revalidate()` and `repaint()` at the end of your `actionPerformed()` method, you will see the `JLabel`s actually get added. You may have to consider using another layout manager though, since the `FlowLayout` will not give you the desired result here. Because you will see, that with your current layout, the `JLabel`s will not be replaced, but always added additionally.

Comment: Now I can see the text with revalidate() but now the texts are being stacked top on each other instead of being replaced. Should I remove FlowLayot then?

Comment: @Han look closely at [maloomeister's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67401994/1552534) answer, You only need one instance of a JLabel.  Just change the text.

Answer (score 3):

When adding or deleting components to your GUI on runtime, you have to tell Swing that you did so. To do this, you should use `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container where the modification happened.

However, in your case, you don't actually need to always add a new `JLabel` on runtime, as you can simply do that when setting up the GUI, and only modifying the label that is already there. By doing it this way, you avoid having to `revalidate()` and `repaint()` (and it is also easier and cleaner this way).

I updated your code and did the following modificiations:

- Moved the declaration and initialization of the `JLabel` out of the `actionPerformed()`, so you don't have to create a new `JLabel` each time a button is pressed. Now, only the text is changed. (A side effect of this change is, that the `revalidate()` and `repaint()` are actually not needed anymore, as no more component is added during runtime)
- Started the GUI on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.
- Usually it is also good practice in Swing to not create a subclass of `JFrame` if this is not specifically needed (like in your case). The better approach is to subclass `JPanel`, add the necessary components there, override `getPreferredSize()` and then add this to the `JFrame`. I have not included this change here, since it might have caused too much confusion.

Updated code:

```
public class ThreeBtn extends JFrame {

    private JButton btnRed;
    private JButton btnGreen;
    private JButton btnBlue;
    private JLabel label;

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Container contentPane = getContentPane();
            if (e.getSource() == btnRed) {
                contentPane.setBackground(Color.red);
                label.setText("red in korean");
            } else if (e.getSource() == btnGreen) {
                contentPane.setBackground(Color.green);
                label.setText("green in korean");
            } else if (e.getSource() == btnBlue) {
                contentPane.setBackground(Color.blue);
                label.setText("blue in korean");
            }
        }
    }

    public ThreeBtn() {
        setSize(300, 200);
        setTitle("Three Button Example");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container cPane = getContentPane();
        cPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        btnRed = new JButton("RED");
        btnGreen = new JButton("GREEN");
        btnBlue = new JButton("BLUE");
        label = new JLabel("");
        label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 25));
        label.setForeground(Color.yellow);

        ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
        btnRed.addActionListener(listener);
        btnGreen.addActionListener(listener);
        btnBlue.addActionListener(listener);

        cPane.add(btnRed);
        cPane.add(btnGreen);
        cPane.add(btnBlue);
        cPane.add(label);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> (new ThreeBtn()).setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

This now works as per your requirements with the used `FlowLayout`. However, you may use another layout manager (or combine different ones) if you plan on doing more with it.

Comment: You don't need to revalidate because you are not adding a new component.

Comment: @WJS yeah correct. With the provided update that is not necessary. I was still editing and clearifying this in the answer just now.

Comment: You may also want to suggest that the OP subclass JPanel and not JFrame and add the panel to the frame.  Regardless, +1.

Comment: Thanks. Good point, however I didn't want to change too much to avoid any confusion. I will still add this as a note.

Answer (score 0):

The Dimensions of the frame and panel where small so they did not show the text when you pressed the buttons.

Dimension size = label.getPreferredSize();
label.setBounds(150, 100, size.width, size.height);

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if there are any rules for your program, but I would suggest, just limiting your if statements in ActionListener to the point where you set the foreground. Then make your JLabel object a class variable, and add the JLabel in the constructor. Here is the full edited code:

---

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ThreeBtn extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton btnRed;
    private JButton btnGreen;
    private JButton btnBlue;
    private JLabel text = new JLabel();
    
    
     public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
         
         public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
             if (e.getSource() == btnRed) {
                 (getContentPane()).setBackground(Color.red);
                 text.setText("red"); //it means "The background is red" in Korean   
                 text.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 25));
                 text.setForeground(Color.yellow);
             }
             else if(e.getSource()==btnGreen) {
                 (getContentPane()).setBackground(Color.green);
                 text.setText("green"); //it means "The background is green" in Korean
                 text.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 25));
                 text.setForeground(Color.yellow);         
             }
             else if(e.getSource()==btnBlue) {
                 (getContentPane()).setBackground(Color.blue);
                 text.setText("blue"); //it means "The background is blue" in Korean
                 text.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 25));
                 text.setForeground(Color.yellow); 
                 (getContentPane()).add(text);
             }
         }
     }
     
     public ThreeBtn() {
         setSize(300, 200);
         setTitle("Three Button Example");
         setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         
         Container cPane = getContentPane();
         cPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
         btnRed = new JButton("RED");
         btnGreen = new JButton("GREEN");
         btnBlue = new JButton("Blue");
         
         ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
         btnRed.addActionListener(listener);
         btnGreen.addActionListener(listener);
         btnBlue.addActionListener(listener);
         
         cPane.add(btnRed);
         cPane.add(btnGreen);
         cPane.add(btnBlue);
         cPane.add(text);
         

     }
     
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         (new ThreeBtn()).setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me, at least. See if it works for you. Simpler approach compared to @maloomeister 's answer